# Push topic message event type is always "updated" even when inserting object

Tags: jsforce, pushtopic, node-salesforce

I'm subscribed to two different push topics, and one of them doesn't register any event types as "Create" only as an "Update".

My config for the working push topic is as follows:

`` {
    "Name": "SaleUpdate",
    "Query": `SELECT 
                  Id
                  , Name
                  , Prospect_Phone_Number_1__c
                  , i360__Prospect_Email__c
                  , i360__Appointment_Address__c
                  , i360__Appointment_City__c
                  , i360__Appointment_State__c
                  , i360__Appointment_Zip__c
                  , i360__Market_Segment__c
                  , i360__Sales_Rep_1__c
                  , i360__Sales_Rep_2__c
                  , i360__Appointment__c
              FROM i360__Sale__c`,
    "ApiVersion": 34.0,
    "NotifyForOperationCreate": true,
    "NotifyForOperationUpdate": true,
    "NotifyForFields": "All"
} ``

And for the push topic that is only receiving updates:

`` {
    "Name": "ProjectUpdate",
    "Query": `SELECT 
                  Id
                  , i360__Sale__c
                  , i360__Project_Number__c
                  , i360__Status__c
                  , i360__Start_Date__c
                  , i360__Completed_On__c
              FROM i360__Project__c`,
    "ApiVersion": 34.0,
    "NotifyForOperationCreate": true,
    "NotifyForOperationUpdate": true,
    "NotifyForFields": "All"
} ``

Is there something I'm doing wrong in creating the push topic? To clarify, whenever I insert an `i360__Project__c`, I receive and event; my problem is that the `message.event.type` is always `"updated"`.

Comment: What happens if you set `NotifyForOperationUpdate` to false and leave `NotifyForOperationCreate` true? Are there any triggers on i360__Project__c that could be causing an update immediately after the insert?